# Using splash-container in Pure CSS

Tags: html, css, navbar, yui-pure-css

I'm using a `splash-container` this way:

```html
<div class="splash-container">
  <div class="splash">
     <h1 class="splash-head">Ciencias de la Legislación</h1>
     <p class="splash-subhead">
       Listado de archivos disponibles.
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```css
.splash-container {
  background: #595959;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*position: fixed !important;*/
}
```

But I have a small space between the navbar and the `splash-containe`, As you can see here:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: do you have a fiddle for your example?

Comment: rightclick the space and inspect it to see where it is coming from, impossible to say without the code

Comment: can yoi add your markup

Comment: Just want to note that `spash-container` is a completely arbitrary name for a container here with no outside meaning, so it's irrelevant to the issue. There's no such thing as "a" splash-container, so this question is named very strangely. With that said, whatever is causing the space is not in the CSS you pasted here. We need to see more.

Comment: Thanks Flink, i found the problem.

Comment: Probably the `h1` element inside the `.splash-container` has a margin-top which cause that space. You can try add `.splash-container h1 { margin-top: 0;}` and it might fix it, but without the complete html/css (working example) it's really hard to know what caused it.